# Drag and Drop image from a list box to a Content Control item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a list box of images and I want to be able to click and drag an image to a content control item and have it display the file path of the image for now.  Does anyone know how I could implement this? I'm very new to WPF. Links to references would also be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately drag and drop in WPF is harder work than you'd like. I personally use the open source library http://code.google.com/p/gong-wpf-dragdrop/.

Or if you want to do more of the work yourself [this](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=53) article is a good place to start.